# PasswordSignIn return Succeed but after redirect to another ActionResult User is not authenticated in net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I user net core 3.1 and EF core to identity and login.
At first , I use passwordSignIn method to signin and returns Succeed after that I retdirectToAction to "profile".

in "Profile" User.Identity.isAuthenticated is false.

As you can see in my code I set sign in complete and works correct. but user is not authenticeted.
here is my sign in:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = _db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            var res = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, true, false);
            if (res.Succeeded)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("profile");


            }

        }


        return View();
    }
```

and here is profile:

```
public IActionResult Profile()
    {
        var t = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        var n = User.Identity.Name;
        var s = User.Claims.ToList();
        var x = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        var ss = User.IsInRole("Admin");
        return View();
    }
```

and here is my start up :

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(Encryptor.Decrypt(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>();
        var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
        identityBuilder.AddRoles<UserRole>();
        identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();
        identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {

            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie("Identity.Application");
    }
 
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**Update StartUp**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(Encryptor.Decrypt(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        });

        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
        var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
        identityBuilder.AddRoles<Role>();
        identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        });
        

      


        
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie("Identity.Application");
    
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }



        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: I check the solution in stackoverflow but I did all of them . maybe there is a problem with startup?

Comment: Please try to explicitly apply `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on action method to specify the authentication scheme(s) to use, then check if it can work well.

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu . thanks for your attention. I did it but not worked.

Comment: Or add `app.UseCookiePolicy();`?

Comment: @Yinqiu I update start up in question. now I get this error: 
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Cookies'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Cookies",...)?

Comment: is it any wrong with my start up?

Comment: just  to remove the explicit "Application" name to default "Cookies" name

Comment: @Yinqiu you mean .AddCookie("Identity"); instead of .AddCookie("Identity.Application");?

Comment: you can try `.AddCookie()`

Comment: @Yinqiu I did. now the error change to: InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Application'. The registered sign-in schemes are: Cookies. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookies("Identity.Application",...)?

Comment: this is :  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

Comment: `.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

Comment: @Yinqiu thank you very much for your kindness. finally I add this to signin method:
var claims = new[] 
{ 
    new Claim("name", authUser.Username)
};

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
and it works with addCookie("cookie").

Comment: I did not know how it solve the problem but works.
could you please tell me how it solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve problem with the help of [@Yinqiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13973037/yinqiu) and a bit more search.
I add these lines to signin method:

```
    var claims = new[] 
{ 
    new Claim("name", authUser.Username)
};

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

I dont have any idea about how it solve but it works.

of course I change  line in start up class :

```
... .AddCookie("Cookie");
```